# Confused: Pointers to Dynamic Arrays Syntax

Tags: c++

```
int* p_bob = new int;

*p_bob = 78;
```

The above code makes sense to me.  I use the de-reference operation to allocation new memory and assign a value of 78.

```
int* p_dynint = new int[10];
*p_dynint[2] = 12;
```

This however doesn't make sense.  If I try to use the de-reference operator on p_dynint[] I get an error.  Why would an array be any different?

Comment: Don't you ever, EVER go and use `new` again, ya hear me? Use `std::make_shared` or something like that....

Comment: "Ever" is a bit extreme, though I get your point.  For example, I believe you have no choice but to use `new` with a `unique_ptr`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`*p_bob = 78;` this assigns the value `78` to the memory pointed to by `p_bob` (which represents an `int`).

`p_dynint[2] = 12;` simply accesses the 3rd element.

`p_dynint[2]` is actually equivalent to `*(p_dynint+2)`.

Answer (score 2):

`p_dynint[2]` is equivalent to `*(p_dynint + 2)`. The derefencing is implied in the `[]` operator.

Answer (score -1):

It is no real problem to do this:

```
int* p_dynint=new int[10];
//write first element
*p_dynint=10;
//write second element
*(p_dynint+1)=20;
//write three elements to std::cout
std::cout<<p_dynint[0]<<p_dynint[1]<<p_dynint[10]<<std::endl;
```

This example also highlights a problem with arrays. You can read and write **anything**. The output generated by `p_dynint[10]` is an int but its value is just the next few bytes converted to an int.

Use containers if possible (for further reasoning read [this](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/containers.html#faq-34.1))

Comment: Actually, no. `p_dynint[10]` results in undefined behavior, and anything can happen. Including a crash.